# Qt Optional Argument has no matching function call

Tags: c++, qt

I'm getting a compile error when trying to use a method defined as having and option argument. The error message is this:

> error: no matching function for call to 'ConsoleWidget::logInfo(const
>   char [32])'consoleWidget->logInfo("This is logging an info message");

Below are my files.

**(header) .h**

```
#ifndef CONSOLEWIDGET_H
#define CONSOLEWIDGET_H

#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QAction>
#include <QColor>

class ConsoleWidget : public QTextEdit
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit ConsoleWidget(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

public slots:
    void logInfo(const QString& text, const bool includeTimestamp /*=false*/);
};

#endif // CONSOLEWIDGET_H
```

**cpp (.cpp)**

```
void ConsoleWidget::logInfo(const QString &text, bool includeTimestamp = false)
{
    ...
}
```

**(main) .cpp**

```
auto *consoleWidget = new ConsoleWidget(this);
consoleWidget->logInfo("This is logging a message!");
```

Comment: That's because `main.cpp` doesn't know about the default argument value as it's defined in the the `.cpp` file. Try defining the default argument in the header instead

Comment: The default argument value must be declared in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

A default argument is (secretly) evaluated and passed by the caller of the function, so it must be known where the function is called.

If the compiler has seen

```
 void foo(int x = 37);
```

and then encounters

```
foo();
```

it will replace that with the equivalent of

```
foo(37);
```

If it has seen only `void foo(int x);`, there will not be a function with a matching prototype, because the function *always* takes an `int` parameter.

(This is different from, for instance, Python, where default arguments are evaluated when the function is defined and the calling code doesn't need to care.)

The solution is to move your default value from the function definition to its declaration.